# how to make voip calls using siri-kit iOS10

Tags: ios, xcode, sirikit

I have added extension to app(as per apple documentation) but intent handler class is not responding with my commands. what i am missing don't no.Please help me ,How can i add siri to my app.

```
 // reslove
- (void)resolveContactsForStartAudioCall:(INStartAudioCallIntent *)intent
                          withCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray<INPersonResolutionResult *> *resolutionResults))completion{
    NSArray *contacts;
    NSArray * contacts1;
    INPersonResolutionResult* result = nil;
    if (contacts == intent.contacts) {
        for (INPerson *contact in contacts) {

       contacts1 = [self contactsMatchingName:contact.displayName];
            switch (contacts1.count) {
                case 1:
                    result = [contacts objectAtIndex:0];
                    [INPersonResolutionResult successWithResolvedPerson:[contacts1 objectAtIndex:0]];
                    break;
                case 0:
                    result = [INPersonResolutionResult unsupported];
                    break;
                default:
                    result  = [ INPersonResolutionResult disambiguationWithPeopleToDisambiguate:contacts1];
                    break;
            }
        }
        completion(contacts1);
    }else{
        result =  [INPersonResolutionResult needsValue];
    }


}

// confirmation method
- (void)confirmStartAudioCall:(INStartAudioCallIntent *)intent
                   completion:(void (^)(INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *response))completion{

    INStartAudioCallIntentResponse *result = nil;
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"isSignedIn"]) {
        result = [[INStartAudioCallIntentResponse alloc]initWithCode:INStartAudioCallIntentResponseCodeReady userActivity:nil];
        completion(result);
    }else{
        NSUserActivity  *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc]initWithActivityType:@"reLogin"];
        result = [[INStartAudioCallIntentResponse  alloc]initWithCode:INStartAudioCallIntentResponseCodeFailure userActivity:activity];
        completion(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: [Apple's Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) implements Siri but unfortunately it's in Swift. Add the CoreLocation.framework to the app and activate it in Settings | Siri, and test it using a phone number as it doesn't recognise Contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few resources to get you started.

1. Guides and Documentation

[SiriKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1)

[Intents Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents)

[IntentsUI Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intentsui)

2. Sample Code

[UnicornChat Sample App](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/UnicornChat/Introduction/Intro.html)

3. Videos (from WWDC 2016)

[Introducing SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/217/)

[Extending your app with SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/225/)

Comment: @asdrubai  Thank you giving tutorials i read this documentation before only

Comment: I am new to iOS development. I added all extensions to project but intend handler is not calling when i use siri

Comment: @NagendarReddy Perhaps you can visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to better ask your question and make it easier for people to help you. General questions are harder to answer

Comment: thank you for suggestion . i added code above please see what i have to do

Comment: He said he read the documentation, as have I, and it doesn't give VoIP examples. It doesn't explain how to put it all together. Your answer isn't helpful at all. I wish StackOverflow would get rid of condescending answers like this.

Comment: @BillK It wasn't my intention to be condescending at all. When OP asked the question and when I answered and commented on OP's questions, the question didn't include their code which is why I posted my answer/comments as I did. You can look at the edits to verify.